# Is there a function, continuous on the irrationals, with rational values, nowhere locally constant?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, baire-category

**Question.** *Let $\mathbb A=\mathbb R\!\smallsetminus\!\mathbb Q$ be the irrational numbers. Is there a continuous function $\,f:\mathbb A\to\mathbb Q$, which is nowhere locally constant? – i.e., for every $a<b$, the restriction $f\,\big|_{\,(a,b)\cap\mathbb A}$ is not constant.*

Clearly, there exist many non-constant such functions, which are continuous, but *fail* to be *nowhere locally constant*.

One failed attempt: Let $\mathbb Q=\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, and set 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N} a_n\mathrm{sgn}(x-q_n),\tag{1}
$$
where $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb Q^+$, with $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n<\infty$.
Clearly $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb A$, and it does not take necessarily only rational values.

**EDIT.** If there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset\mathbb Q^+$, such that $\sum_{n\in S}a_n\in\mathbb Q$, for every $S\subset\mathbb N$, then the function $f$, defined by $(1)$ possesses the sought for properties.

Comment: I would say no because you'd have to distribute an uncountably infinite number of irrationals among a countably infinite number of rationals within every interval of $x\pm\delta$; I may be wrong though, because this is only my first thought and I haven't made it rigorous at all.

Comment: Wouldn't the restriction of $f(x) = x$ to the irrationals have this property, or am I missing something?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro $f:\mathbb A\to\mathbb Q$, so $f(x)\in\mathbb Q$, for all $x$.

Comment: Oh, I see ... you want the Range to be a subset of the rational numbers. I'll leave my comments up in case someone else misses this aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such function and one way to show this makes use of the Baire category theorem.

Assume that $f:{\mathbb A} \rightarrow {\mathbb Q}$ is continuous. For each $r \in {\mathbb Q},$ let $E_r = f^{-1}(r)$ be the inverse image of the set $\{x\}$ under $f.$ Note that ${\mathbb A} = \cup \{E_r: r \in {\mathbb Q}\}.$ Because $\mathbb A$ cannot be written as a countable union of nowhere-dense-in-${\mathbb A}$ sets (by the Baire category theorem; recall that $\mathbb A$ is [completely metrizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_metrizable_space)), at least one of the "$E_r$ sets" is not nowhere-dense-in-${\mathbb A},$ which means that at least one of the "$E_r$ sets", say $E_{r_0},$ is somewhere dense in ${\mathbb A}.$ Also, since $f$ is continuous, each $E_r$ is a closed set in ${\mathbb A}.$ In particular, $E_{r_0}$ is closed in ${\mathbb A}.$ It follows that $E_{r_0}$ contains an ${\mathbb A}$-interval, and because $f$ takes only the value $r_0$ on this interval, it follows that $f$ is constant on this interval.